# wp_get_attachment_image does not return medium sized images

Tags: wordpress, function

I read through the codex for these 2 functions:

`wp_get_attachment_image`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image

`wp_get_attachment_image_src`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

But when I try to run it specifying an image size it still returns the full sized image.

```
$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_id, 'medium' );
```

On the codex page under the `$size` definition for both functions say:

> "As of Version 2.5, this parameter does not affect the size of media icons, which are always shown at their original size."

Alternatively I've tried `get_the_post_thumbnail` and `image_downsize` with no luck.

Essentially I have the `$post_id` for the attachment and I want to extract the url for the medium sized image.

Comment: I should add I'm running Wordpress 3.5.1

Answer (score 0):

> First to get image_id then pass argument in
>   wp_get_attachment_image_src():

```
$image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'medium');
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually I am using the plugin *Automatic Featured Image Posts* and found a more in-depth discussion here:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-automatic-featured-image-posts-add-image-to-body-of-post-as-well-as-adding-featured-image

I was trying to insert the medium sized image source into my posts through the plugin functions, but it ended up easier to display the medium sized thumbnail image in my theme template instead using:

`the_post_thumbnail('medium');`

Thanks for the reply!